# Why css is not applied for a component of one app into another app in vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-loader

Hi i have situation where `css` and `scss` is not applied of a component of `1 app` into another `app`

I have 2 apps

1. core
2. plugins

i want to use the components of a `core` app into `plugins` app

here is how i'm doing

**Core App**

```
//main.js

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
const app1 = new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    ....
})

//core.component.vue

<template>
   .....
</template>
<script>
   export default{
       name:'CoreComponent',
       ....
    }
</script>
<styles lang="scss" scoped>
   $bgColor:red;   <--- these css are not applied when used in app 2
   ...             <--- these css are not applied when used in app 2
</styles>
```

Core provides component mappers for providing component when requested to `plugins`.

```
//core-component-mapper.js

export default{
  CoreComponent: require('path/CoreComponent.vue').default,
}
```

**Below my `plugins` App setup**

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import CoreComponentMapper 'path/core-component-mapper.js'

const app2 = new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    components:{
      FirstCoreComp: CoreComponentMapper.CoreComponent,
    },
})
```

**Note:** please ignore any mistake in my demo code, code works perfectly in my setup **except `user defined css` is not applied**

**Question:** whichever `css` is defined on `component` of `app 1` i,e `core` by me is not applied when used in `App 2` i,e `plugins`

**Note:** i did not setup any `webpack` config i guess my both `vue` app is using default `vue-loader` config

Intresting thing is that `bootstrap` css works don't know why.(it is used in both the `apps`)

**@MatJ**  as you asked in one of your comment i'm attaching screenshot (**as per me css are not merged , but inline css are applied well**)

[image]

[image]

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: You added the `scoped` attribute for the style tag. That means that style is applicable only for within the component and vue will generate necessary wrapping code to make sure the style does not leak to other parts. You can inspect the items and see. Remove that `scoped` attribute form style tag and it will work as soon as component is displayed.

Comment: @MatJ Recommend that you answer questions with answers, not in comments :) Especially here, with a 50p bounty awaiting!

Comment: @MatJ, whatever you said is correct but within `core app` i,e `App1` it is required so that it should not mess with other styles. is there any workaround without changing `scoped` attribute.

It was put purposely.

Comment: @Sebastian, Writing answers is time consuming, I've to keep it clean and in good quality. Helping someone with quick tips in comments is not. Anyone patient enough to convert my comments to answers is welcome to do so. That is exactly what I expect.

Comment: @EaBengaluru, no workaround with scoped attribute. If you are aware of the scoped attribute and its behavior, you should update the question to reflect that. As it stands, you asks why and the reason is because it is scoped.

Comment: @MatJ , that being said. my question is why it works within same app with `scoped` attribute. not in another app.

Comment: Because the style is scoped, the style is declared inside the Core App as scoped, so vue will generrate a unique attribute for all nodes that come under the core app's root node and wrap your style to apply only to those nodes with this specific attribute. You can take developer tools in your web browser and check the styles section. Your styles will appear with an attribute suffix like `.test[data-v-258a58b9]{   color: red; }`

Comment: @EaBengaluru [Here is an illustration](https://i.imgur.com/lK0xtZ9.png)

Comment: @MatJ, as you said above in last 2 comments with illustration(thanks for that) i removed `scoped` attribute and compiled and built the app result is same. everything works except `css`

Comment: We are missing something then. Can you add a screenshot to your question similar to my illustration? How the style is shown in the styles panel and how it appears  when it works and when it doesn't?

Comment: @MatJ, as you asked me to upload something similar to your illustration i have upload it. please check my question now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the css that are not being applied are inside a scoped block:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
```

and this is exactly how scoped css in vue are supposed to work.

If you wish to have a common shared style, just put the variables you need in a separate .css file and import it like you do with the bootstrap css.

Comment: Or remove `scoped`. Also, it's `style` and not `styles`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an article](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/styling-vue-single-file-components) explaining properly all the solutions that are available with Vue3 `style` tag.

Here, you could either:

- remove `scoped` from your `style` tag (it's not **styles** btw)
- inject some global CSS coming from another file higher in the app
- use the new `:global(.your-query-selector)`
  [selector](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#global-selectors).